Slab Leak Repair - $5,830 Quote
I wanted to get your input on a quote I received for fixing a hot water pipe leak under my floor.
A couple of weeks ago, I noticed a spot on my floor was warm/hot to the touch, so I called out American Leak Detectors to check it out. They confirmed there’s a hot water pipe leak under the floor. To add to my concerns, I just got my water bill for this month, and it jumped 4x higher than usual—from around $20 to about $80. Definitely not normal for me.
Here’s the plan they laid out:

They said rerouting the pipe isn’t an option because of exterior wall limitations.
They’ll dig to the pipe on the first day, repair it on the second day, and then bring in city inspectors to confirm it’s been fixed correctly.

The total quote for this job is $5,830.
I’m in Dallas, and I’m scheduled to go ahead with them on Monday. But before I do, I wanted to see if this price seem reasonable for this kind of repair?

I’m voting to close this question because pricing checks are off-topic for this group.

We do not do prices.  Get more than one quote or can do this yourself.  Can rent a cement saw to cut the floor, fix the pipe and re cement.

Though if one pipe is leaking, depending on the reason, it could mean that all of your under-slab piping is likely to leak, especially if the leaking spot is leaking due to corrosion.

@DIY75 they're digging 3ft by 3ft by 3ft

@crip659 I'm mostly worried about it in it's current situation, my water bill increased dramatically and the plumber kind of put the fear in god in me by saying that it needs to get done on Monday...

cut the concrete with diamond saw (3x3) then dig till you find the pipes, usually the concrete is 6-8 inches thick, when done call a plumber to fix the pipe

plumber kind of put the fear in god in me by saying that it needs to get done on Monday ... that makes no sense ... why the urgency?

why would they have to dig down three feet?

There should be a shut off valve for that line.  That will stop the leaking till it is fixed.

@crip659 yeah, i've just been turning the hot water heater off when i haven't been using it.

@jsotola might have been mistaken with the 3 feet down.

@SolarMike if the water bill increased, then the leak is probably more than a few days old ... the urgency voiced by the plumber may be a sales tactic
